# Как правильно преобразовать массив для отправки по API?

Tags: php, json, api

Всем привет. Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста.
Есть массив в формате

```
{
"status": "ok",
"timestamp": 1542871773703,
"data": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "7",
    "creationDate": 1539265369000,
}}
```

Чтобы отправить данные через POST по API необходимо удалить

```
    {
"status": "ok",
"timestamp": 1542871773703,
"data":
```

Со статусом и timestamp проблем нет -

```
unset($response1['status']);
unset($response1['timestamp']);
```

А вот как удалить "data": ? Так чтобы сам массив остался.
Чтобы можно было его отправить через Post.
Проще говоря POST по API должен выглядеть в формате

```
{
        "id": 7,
        "name": "7",
        "creationDate": 1539265369000,
    }
```

Comment: а почему не можешь просто отправить data? то есть, отправляй $response1['data']. тогда у тебя будет только то, что в дата

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v,$k) use (&$data) { $k=="data"? $data=$v : null; });

print_r($data);
```

Это аналог foreach

```
foreach($array as $k=>$v){
    if($k=="data") $data=$v;
}
```